# Inserting data into monogodb via node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I run this app.js. The problem is that I can not add collections(insert data). What should I do?
It seems that I was succefully connected to the server.

This is my app.js code.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

main().catch(err => console.log(err));

async function main() {
  // Use connect method to connect to the server
  await mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/FruitsDB');

  const fruitSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    rating: Number,
    review: String
  });

  const Fruit = mongoose.model('Fruit', fruitSchema);

  const fruit = new Fruit({
    name: 'Apple',
    rating: 7,
    review: 'Pretty solid as a fruit.'
  });

 // await fruit.save();

  const fruits = await Fruit.find();
  console.log(fruits);

  const personSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    age: Number
  });

  const Person = mongoose.model('Person', personSchema);

  const person = new Person({
    name: 'John',
    age: 37
  });

 // await person.save();

  const people = await Person.find();
  console.log(people);

  const kiwi = new Fruit({
    name: 'Kiwi',
    score: 10,
    review: 'The best fruit!'
  });

  const orange = new Fruit({
    name: 'Orange',
    score: 4,
    review: 'Too sour for me'
  });

  const banana = new Fruit({
    name: 'Banana',
    score: 3,
    review: 'Weird texture'
  });



  Fruit.insertMany([kiwi, orange, banana])
  .then(function () {
    console.log("Successfully saved defult items to DB");
  })
  .catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err);
  });

}
```

As you can see below, there is no data in the FruitsDB.

[image]

By the way, this is what I got from the terminal.

```
FruitsProject % node app.js
[]
[]
Successfully saved defult items to DB
```

I tried different types of codes but I still can not add any data to the database.

Comment: There shouldn't be a collection named `collection`, mongoose names the collections after the models. What does `show collections` return?